# special case for stopping time

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes

I am a little confused about a spacial case of stopping time:

Let X = $\{X_n : n ≥ 0\}$ be any stochastic process and suppose that $\tau$
is any random time that is independent of $X$. Then $\tau$ is a stopping time.

Based on my understanding, $\tau$ is a stopping time if $\{\tau =n \} \in \sigma(X_0,X_1,...,X_n)$, then it means that $\{\tau =n \}$ realized or not is known at time n, right? But for the above context, knowing $X$ gives no information of knowing $\tau$, thus we can not know whether $\{\tau =n \}$ realized or not at time n, then why could this be a stopping time?